# Setting preferred font substitution in Scribus

Tags: fonts, scribus

A similar question wanted to know how to set a font substitution in a template. My question is how to setup font substitution in the Scribus preferences. There is a tab for it, but I am missing how to type in the font and what to substitute for it.  I seriously can find no way to enter anything into the dialog box! I've tried right click, left click, simply typing, clicking any of the buttons at the bottom -nothing. It's as if the place where one expects to create a list is just an image.

If you are a Scribus user, please show screen shots of how you manage to type in the font name and the replacement. No one else seems to have this problem -so I must be missing something obvious.

thanks for help
Windows 7
Scribus 1.4.5

[image]

Comment: this is a tech support question, not a design one.

Comment: @Luciano: I do not want to debate that fuzzy category, but this question is certainly something that designers working with Scribus can answer rather than general computer experts. The answer also demonstrates that this is not a general computer issue. This makes it on-topic as per [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/19174).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say it like this: You cannot define a font substitution in Scribus.

It's Scribus that will ask you to pick a substitute font, when it detects a missing font.
The list you have found in the preferences, is only there to allow you remove a substitution that you have set. If you now have the font installed or if you want to pick a different font. If Scribus still needs a substitution the next time Scribus will ask again for it.

If you want to change a font used in a specific document, you can redefine the style to use it (you're using styles, aren't you?) or use the search and replace tool... but -- currently -- you will need to do so for each chain for text frames.